# how to allow nginx to allow /forum

Tags: nginx, drupal

so we have a nginx and drupal site and the the folder structure looks like this

/my_site   [ drupal site root]

/mysite/index.php [ drupal main index file]

/my_site/forum [ I created this folder this is not a standard drupal folder]

/my_site/forum/viewforum.php  [I put this php file to do some custom logic ]

/my_site/forum/      [there is no index.php file as I want drupal to handle /forum and show the default forum module which it has]

everything works fine except when some goes to /forum they get forbidden 403 as there is no index file.

I have tried:

1) Making a symlink to point to the main index file

2) redirecting back to drupal root but then /forum just does not work

I am not sure how I can get nginx to allow drupal to handle /forum but not /forum/viewforum.php Please help

Comment: Can you post snippets of your nginx config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have already implemented Drupal routing features in your configuration.

To solve your issue, you should add this snippet in your configuration:

```
location = /forum {
    rewrite ^ /index.php last;
}
```

I assume `my_site` is your webroot, so that your `index.php` is in the root folder.